# Insertar archivos en BBDD de SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

Estamos trabajando en un proyecto de almacenamiento de archivos en la "nube" mediante el uso de Java y conexión mediante sockets.

Tenemos como insertar valores en la BBDD (en este caso se inserta 'hello' en la posición 1 de la tabla 'msg')

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                 "jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE msg(id INT, content TEXT)");
        int count = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO msg VALUES(1, 'hello')");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM msg");
        while (rs.next()) {
         int x = rs.getInt(1);
         String s = rs.getString(2);
         System.out.println(x + " - " + s);
        }

        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

La duda surge a la hora de insertar archivos de cualquier tipo (texto, imágenes, etc...) en la BBDD.

Si alguien puede aportar la metodología para realizar nuestro propósito nos hará un gran favor. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Es estrictamente necesario almacenar los archivos en BBDD?
En mi opinión, deberíais guardar los archivos en un repositorio tipo Amazon s3 (por ejemplo) o crear un servidor dedicado al almacenamiento de archivos y almacenar en BBDD la url del archivo en el repositorio. Esta opción os permitirá guardar cualquier tipo de archivo y poner vosotros el límite de tamaño y las restricciones de formato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aunque estoy un poco verde en insercion de imagenes en una BD creo que esto seria asi. En MySQL se suele usar "Datos de objeto binario grande" (Blob en ingles, suele soportar imagenes de con poca carga, entre 5kb o 10 sino me equivoco. Lo primero seria crear una tabla que soporte este formato. Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE imagenes(
id varchar(49) DEFAULT NULL,
size int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
image longblob
);
```

Y en java lo insertarías con un código, y lo recalco, parecido:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("Insertar imagen");
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:2019/";
    String dbNombre = "prueba";
    String usuario = "root";
    String contraseña= "root";
    Connection con = null;
    try{
       Class.forName(driver);
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbNombre,usuario,contraseña);
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       File imgarchivo = new File("imagen.jpg");

      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgarchivo);

       PreparedStatement pre =
       con.prepareStatement("insert into imagenes values(?,?,?)");

       pre.setString(1,"prueba");
       pre.setInt(2,3);
       pre.setBinaryStream(3,(InputStream)fin,(int)imgarchivo.length());
       pre.executeUpdate();
       System.out.println("La inserción ha sido exitosa");

       pre.close();
       con.close(); 
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // Para saber si falla
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o te acerque un poco mas a la solución.